# Technique for performing a search that returns a key rather than sorting in place

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

In many situations I need to know the sorted order of an array, not sort the array. For example, imagine there are five (5) arrays containing various information of different types (string, int, double etc) and the arrays are synchronized, meaning that the n-th element of each array goes together. Imagine now that the first array has a "name" value, a string and I want to eliminate all values with duplicate names. I need to get a sort key for the name array and use that to eliminate the duplicates in all five arrays. I cannot sort the name array because then it would no longer be synchronized with the other arrays.

To solve this problem I have been writing my own sort routines. Originally, I had several different versions of QuickSort (depending on the data type, whether the arrays are one-based or zero-based, and what kind of sort it is, ascending, descending, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, etc) and recently I have been experimenting with making various kinds of radix sorts which I have found to be faster than QuickSort for some kinds of data. My routines return sort keys, rather than sort the array itself. In other words they return an array containing integers, each integer indicating which element of the target array(s) belongs in that place. So, for example, if the first value of the sort key is 43 then it means the 43rd element of the target array is the first element in the sorted order.

Now, while it is fascinating and educating to be writing all these sorting routines, I am wondering whether there is a better technique for doing this that allows me to leverage existing sorting libraries? Is there a way I can obtain a sort key using standard library resources in Java/C?

***Update***

I tried the indirect sorting method recommended by Juan Lopez and it seems to work. Code:

```
private final static void test_indirect_sort(){
    final String[] test_array = { "pear", "peach", "doggie", "apple", "dog", "prairie", "a", "tundra", "flamingo", "barn" };
    Integer[] sorted_keys = new Integer[test_array.length];
    for( int i = 0; i < sorted_keys.length; i++ ) sorted_keys[i] = i;
    java.util.Arrays.sort(sorted_keys, new java.util.Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return test_array[o1].compareTo(test_array[o2]);
        }
    });
    for( int xKey = 0; xKey < sorted_keys.length; xKey++ ) System.out.print( test_array[sorted_keys[xKey]] + " " );
    System.out.println();
    for( int xKey = 0; xKey < sorted_keys.length; xKey++ ) System.out.print( test_array[xKey] + " " );
    System.out.println();
}
```

The main drawback of this solution is the need for Integer objects rather than primitive ints, which means at least a 4x increase in space for the key array and slow down for accessing ints inside an Integer wrapper.

***Note on Performance***

From the comments it seems that some people seem to think using arrays of objects is just as fast as using parallel arrays. When I run the following code:

```
private final static void testArrayAccess(){
    int[] a = new int[30000000];
    int[] b = new int[30000000];
    int[] c = new int[30000000];
    MultiArray[] list = new MultiArray[30000000];
    java.util.Random random = new Random();
    for( int x = 0; x < 30000000; x++ ){
        a[x] = random.nextInt(100);
        b[x] = random.nextInt(100);
        c[x] = random.nextInt(100);
        list[x] = new MultiArray();
        list[x].a = a[x];
        list[x].b = b[x];
        list[x].c = c[x];
    }

    long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int sum = 0;
    for( int x = 0; x < 30000000; x++ ){
        sum += a[x] +  b[x] + c[x];
    }
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sum = 0;
    for( int x = 0; x < 30000000; x++ ){
        sum += list[x].a +  list[x].b + list[x].c;
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.format( "parallel arrays: %d  bundled object: %d\n", (end1 - start1), (end2-start2) );
}
```

I get the output:

```
parallel arrays: 4  bundled object: 15
```

showing that in this test case on my system using bundled objects is almost 4x slower than using parallel arrays (not to mention using more memory). To see exactly why it is slower, here is the byte code disassembly for the `sum +=` statements, parallel arrays on left, bundled object on right:

```
   LINENUMBER 32 L20     LINENUMBER 39 L27
    ILOAD 7               ILOAD 7
    ALOAD 0               ALOAD 3
    ILOAD 8               ILOAD 12
    IALOAD                AALOAD
    ALOAD 1               GETFIELD cra/common/MultiArray.a : I
    ILOAD 8               ALOAD 3
    IALOAD                ILOAD 12
    IADD                  AALOAD
    ALOAD 2               GETFIELD cra/common/MultiArray.b : I
    ILOAD 8               IADD
    IALOAD                ALOAD 3
    IADD                  ILOAD 12
    IADD                  AALOAD
    ISTORE 7              GETFIELD cra/common/MultiArray.c : I
                          IADD
                          IADD
                          ISTORE 7
```

The byte code on the left will always be slower than the byte code on the right.

Comment: A better technique would be to have just one array, containing instances of a class or data structure whose fields correspond to the data you're keeping in parallel arrays.

Comment: @DonRoby Parallel arrays are only one possible situation in which a sort key is needed. Also, if you use bundled objects there is no way to sort on a particular field without dereferencing the field in the inner loop of the sort (eg by using a comparator) which is very expensive computationally and leads to slow sorting.

Comment: @TylerDurden *"... without dereferencing the field in the inner loop of the sort (eg by using a comparator) which is very expensive computationally and leads to slow sorting."* Huh? Accessing fields is not "computationally expensive". If the fields you are sorting on require computation to access, then you need to consider not re-computing fields used as sort keys every time you access them. You'll have to elaborate more on your claim here, because as you state it, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @TylerDurden Also, be wary of falling into an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @JasonC Bundled objects are fine for small arrays, but when working with arrays of millions of elements you begin to notice the performance penalty of working with objects. For example, instead of having, say, 5 ints, now you have 5 ints *inside an object*, which now have to be dereferenced so you pay both a space and performance penalty.

Comment: @Tyler What you say makes no sense. Looking up array elements like in `test_array[o1].compareTo(test_array[o2])` is at least as costly as dereferencing two pointers after adding some constant offset (to get the respective property of the object). In fact both will result in almost the same machine-level instructions. You don't pay any space penalty, because you only have pointers, not copies of the objects in your array. I think you are prematurely optimizing here and in this case it leads to much worse code

Comment: @NiklasB. If you take the example code from my questions, change the test array to be 600 million random ints and then try to run it on a normal 32-bit PC, you will find it will not even be able to run without exhausting memory because of the object overhead.

Comment: @TylerDurden That makes no sense again because for every int you have an associated string, which needs much more memory than the int alone. A pointer to an object is 32-bits on a 32-bit machine, just like a 32-bit integer, so you gain nothing by using array offsets instead of pointers. And an object needs no more space than the sum of its members need, so you also gain nothing there. I think we have some confusion about performance and memory efficiency there...

Comment: @TylerDurden That has nothing to do with "object overhead" (or "32-bit"-ness) and everything to do with the fact that you try to allocate a ~2.4GB array with too small of a max heap size. `new Integer[600000000]` is the same. `new int[600000000]` is the same. `new String[600000000]` is the same. That's not really related to parallel vs. single arrays... I think you need to experiment a little bit more before you can make sound statements here. Your concerns are valid, but your reasoning is misguided.

Comment: @TylerDurden Perhaps you should consider other ways of storing your data if memory usage is becoming an issue. For example, store your objects in an external database, and use proper database indexes and SQL queries to manipulate your data. These are highly optimized. You need to consider *what* you are doing and *why* you are doing it, there may be better approaches at a higher level. Again I refer you to http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341. For example, what specific application are you working on right now?

Comment: @NiklasB. see updated question for code example showing how using objects results in significantly slower run time.

Comment: @JasonC I think what you are missing is that when you use primitive values bundled in an object which is then in an array you have to dereference twice, once for the object array, then a second time for the field, but for parallel arrays you only dereference once, for the array itself. See example code in the question proving using objects is slower.

Comment: "to dereference twice, once for the object array, then a second time for the field" That's not how objects work. You need just one machine instruction to get from the object pointer to the value stored in a field. And packing three fields into an object does *not* use more space than those three fields combined.

Comment: @NiklasB. the statement listofprimitives[x].primitive1 has TWO dereferences, one for the array containing the objects, and a second dereference of the field inside the object (see example code in question).

Comment: @TylerDurden Again, I must stress that any *possible* cost of dereferencing objects is generally negligible compared to higher level algorithms, which, again, is why you should really tell us *what* you are trying to do and what your goals are. For example, in the specific application you are referring to, you say you are removing duplicates; why not use a set of some kind? If you are storing only strings, why not store them in, say, a trie to begin with? It is a space-efficient set. Or why not use a separate database? Why is your application a secret?

Comment: @JasonC As I said in my question, this need for key-based sorting is something that comes in a lot of different problems where for one reason or another you do not want to sort the original array, you want to leave it the way it is and just know its sort order. ~~~ I know dereferencing the field is one dereference, but you also have to get the bundled object out of the array in the first place, which is a second dereference.

Comment: @TylerDurden No, it's just ONE dereference, you get the field lookup for free by just adding a constant to the pointer. And I don't believe your benchmark results. On my machines the "bundled object" is 3 times *faster*, which is to be expected because the cache efficiency is much better. Please warmup your JIT before benchmarking: http://pastie.org/8961859 But even without the warmup I get even worse result for the "parallel arrays". Maybe you should use a better JVM? I'm using Oracle Java 7 (HotSpot 64-bit)

Comment: @TylerDurden I also noticed that you are cheating in your benchmark, because usually you would have indirection even for the "parallel arrays" case, if I understood your question correctly. So it's double busted, because even having *more* indirection doesn't cause the slowness you claim (in fact the cache efficiency is much more important than the indirection)

Comment: Sorry man, you seem totally resistant to advice, so go ahead and do it the way you want. I *could* go on to debunk your statement "will always be slower than the byte code on the right" but I'm too tired now

Comment: @TylerDurden It certainly can be one dereference. Don't forget about the x86's ability to access pointers with offsets (e.g. `[base_in_register + field_offset]` and `[base_in_register + size * index_in_register]`), which is the same cost as a simple `[offset]`, with perhaps slightly different latency (I don't recall). Even in Java, HotSpot will take care of this for you.

Comment: @NiklasB. I cannot understand why the bundled code would run faster on your machine. I have shown the byte code for each sum statement in the question and obviously the object dereferences (GETFIELD operations) will be a lot slower than the array ops on the left.

Comment: @TylerDurden And you are still avoiding the fundamental issue which is: It depends on your application. You're trying to come up with a general solution to a problem that varies wildly depending on requirements. You simply *cannot* come up with the solution you are looking for in this situation. You have to take into account *what* you are doing, and handle it case-by-case. You are essentially attempting to micro-optimize a general set of problems, and that is just not possible.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, theoretically you could do the dereference with a single such assembly instruction, but that is not actually how it happens, even in C++. In Java you can see how the byte code works, multiple derences including an expensive GETFIELD operation.

Comment: Putting that one aside, in a real scenario you would *not* have an array of integers with your approach. You would have a comparator like `return test_array[o1].compareTo(test_array[o2]);` as in your code sample, which *also* is a form of indirection. So it's ONE indirection vs. ONE indirection per comparison. The byte code is *NOT* what will be executed. It will be transformed into *machine code* optimized for the target platform.

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes it *is* what actually happens, in Java as well as C++. Sorry you are just plain wrong in that regard.

Comment: @TylerDurden It's how it happens in the code I just compiled with MSVC and optimizations on. It's how it happens in the code I just compiled with GCC with optimizations on. It's how it happened the last time I looked at a HotSpot JIT dump with a similar GETFIELD. Now you're just wasting our time with blind conjecture framed as fact. **And you sidestepped the point in my previous comment about optimizing per situation.** At this point I cannot see a reason to continue this discussion. The points here are discussed to death elsewhere, and easily observable with experiment and experience.

Comment: @NiklasB. Look, I showed the byte code, it has 3 additional GETFIELD ops compared to the parallel array version. Parallel arrays has 14 operations, object list has 17 operations, and moreover the 3 extra ops that the object version has are relatively slow ops.

Comment: @TylerDurden Dude, now you're just ignoring what Jason and I wrote in the last three comments. **The byte code is NOT what is executed on the machine**

Comment: @TylerDurden [Turn on HotSpot JIT dumps](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) and show us the assembler.

Comment: @JasonC Ok, I will look at the C++ to see what happens. It may get optimized to be equivalent. I will check it out.

Comment: @TylerDurden But please use a different benchmark to verify your claims to yourself (not to us, because we don't really care). Your current benchmark doesn't reflect your usage scenario, since you can never be able to compare by value directly, only by looking up a value using some sort of indirection

Comment: @NiklasB. In cases where I would use parallel arrays I would not normally be using a comparator. This is actually one of my problems (as stated in the question). I end up with a lot of different sort routines (one for ascending, another for descending, etc) because I don't want the overhead of a comparator in my inner loop.

Comment: @JasonC I compiled a VC++ program with all optimizations and it does indeed convert the primitive field reference to a single indirect reference of the type DWORD PTR _MyObjArray$[esp+1284] where 1284 is a calculated offset. Kind of scary how smart it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an indirection array, and sort it instead of the original one. Example (in Java):

```
final String[] names = {"some", "names", "some"};

Integer[] indirection = new Integer[names.length];
for (int i = 0; i < indirection.length; i++)
    indirection[i] = i;

Arrays.sort(indirection, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return names[o1].compareTo(names[o2]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @TylerDurden No. We're just trolling you.

Comment: I did try this and it seems to work. See code sample in question.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create, for example, a "holder" object that contains original index information, e.g.:

```
static class Holder <T> {
    int originalIndex; 
    T data;
}
```

Then you can store those in your containers, set their `originalIndex` (or whatever) accordingly, then sort (with an appropriate `Comparator`).

After that, you can iterate through the sorted array, and the `originalIndex` (or whatever) will contain the information you are interested in.

A better approach is to not use parallel arrays at all, but instead, as Don Ruby mentions in comments, make proper use of classes to hold all related data in one place. Then, none of this is necessary at all (plus it's easier to pass data around, e.g. instead of passing `firstName[]`, `lastName[]`, and `index`, you just pass around a `Person`).